# Getting value from json by setting key from another json

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to get value from json by using ng-repeat that inside another json loop.

I had tried as below.

```
<tr ng:repeat="tableValueElement in tableValueRows">
         <td ng:repeat="subHeaderElement in subHeaderColumns" ng-init="map=subHeaderElement.map">{{tableValueElement.map}}</td>          
    </tr>
```

tableValueElement = {"name":"Steve","age":24,"street":"RailwayStreet"}

subHeaderElement = {"colspan":2, "map":"name", "color":"grey"}

and I'm trying to get the value ("steve") from "tableValueElement" by setting key ("name") from "subHeaderElement".
So the key is the value of "map" attribute in the "subHeaderElement".

But above method is not returning the value from tableValueElement.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an array notation

```
{{tableValueElement[map]}}
```

Comment: yes, ng-bind approach is the same but the view is more clear while data is loaded

Comment: Thats not worked for me. I tried another method and its working ng-bind=tableValueElement[subHeaderColumn.map]